# How to display My Account portlet as a popup?

Tags: popup, portlet, liferay-6

I want the **My Account** portlet to open as a popup on the click of a link.

This popup should show the left panel(i.e My Submissions,Workflow etc.) only for the admin.
So that rules out making changes in the **portal-ext.properties** file.

A normal user should be able to view the center portion(i.e. fields with the user info) only.

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It has been already implemented in liferay, when you get loggedIn then click over the username in docbar it will open the user account page in pop-up,check it's implementation

Comment: but that popup has a left navigation panel too(My submissions,etc.).I need to get rid of those.